# Using different Apple ID for app testing and for App Store/iTunes purchase on same iPhone?

Tags: iphone, testing

I signed up for the iPhone Developer Program (now awaiting approval) using a new Apple ID, this ID is different from the one I used on my iPhone for iTunes/AppStore purchase.

I only have one iPhone and want to use the same device for app testing and day-to-day phone use. I can not try out yet but I guess iTunes/XCode will use the new Apple ID when I sync my iPhone app for testing. Any idea if I can still continue to use those apps I purchased using the other Apple ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also use separate Apple IDs for the developer program and iTunes purchases. In iTunes, I use the Apple ID I've always used for purchases. I only use my developer program ID for logging in to the developer websites. It all works just fine, even downloading various bits of content from ADC on iTunes. Sufficient magic has been applied.

Answer (score 2):

You can.  It's not a problem.